# Correct way to add association using has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using a has many through association as follows:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :recommendation_ratings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, :through => :recommendation_ratings
end

class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :recommendation_ratings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ratings, :through => :recommendation_ratings
end

class RecommendationRating < ActiveRecord::Base  
  validates :recommendation_id, presence: true
  validates :rating_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :recommendation
  belongs_to :rating
end
```

I am currently creating my associations in my controller as follows:

```
   rr   = RecommendationRating.find_by_recommendation_id(recommendation_id)
   rr ||= RecommendationRating.new(recommendation_id: recommendation_id)

   rr.rating_id = rating_id
   rr.save
```

Alternatively, I could assign ratings to recommendations like so:

```
   @recommendation = Recommendation.find(recommendation_id)
   @rating = Rating.find(rating_id)
   @recommendation.ratings << @rating
```

Which is the correct method to associate these records, and is there a downside to doing it the first way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you need.

The first one updates a `recommendation_rating` record if it already exists and enables you to run callbacks and validation after calling `save`

The second one creates a rating everytime you call `<<` and it creates the record directly on the database so no validation and callback is triggered.

Comment: Is there a way to validated presence of both ID's using the first method?

Comment: Yes, just add a `validates :rating_id, :recommendation_id, presence: true` on `recommendation_rating.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I think I might do

```
RecommendationRating.find_or_create_by_rating_id_and_recommendation_id(
  rating_id,
  recommendation_id
)
```

which, I believe, would be functionally equivalent to both of the methods you described, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I think this is different.  The first method updates an already existing rating for a recommendation.  The second method always creates a rating for a recommendation even though the rating already exists. This creates the rating only if it doesn't exist.